# messenger using message queue and multi thread in single program

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, message

I am trying to write a messenger program in Linux using message queue and pthread.

The program I have written parse the command line arguments to get the ids of the
message queues like

```
user1) ./msg 4321 1234 // snd_key: 4321, rcv_key: 1234 

user2) ./msg 1234 4321 // snd_key: 1234, rcv_key: 4321
```

and then it creates two message queues: one to send, and the other to receive messages.
Then it launches a thread to run sender() passing in &snd_queue as
argument and receiver similarly.
Then I have finished the program by Waiting for the two child threads using pthread_joing and then deallocated the two message queues.

The problem is that I cannot see the **incoming messages** by using two terminals. ( I can only see the message that I type) 
Also, on writing "quit" (which is supposed to end the program), it gives segmentation fault (core dumped).

I cannot understand what is the error in my program ( It does not have any compile errors)

Comment: You should post all what you have done so far.

Comment: @snr What do you mean? This is all what I have done so far.. I have written the whole program. Is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_create(&thread_send, NULL, sender(&snd_queue), NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_recv, NULL, receiver(&rcv_queue), NULL);
```

Both these lines are invalid. The first line is executing the function `sender` and then after it exits, you are creating the thread with the function that is it's return value. Because the return value of `sender` is `return 0;`, you are returning `NULL`, so I hope `pthread_create` fails with `EINVAL`. You want to pass the function pointer for thread creation and also you want toshould check the return value.

```
// error() is a GNU extension from `#include <error.h>

int err = pthread_create(&thread_send, NULL, sender, &snd_queue);
if (err) { error(-1, err, "pthread_create sender failed"); }

err = pthread_create(&thread_recv, NULL, receiver, &rcv_queue);
if (err) { error(-1, err, "pthread_create receiver failed"); }
```